# Connect domain name to AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns

I've created a EC2 machine on AWS and deployed a web server.
I'm able to access it via the machine's external IP.
In addition I've created an Elastic IP for the machine as well.

In the Route 53 I've created a hosted zone with the default SOA & NS and with this type A:[image]

The IP is the elastic IP I've configured in the EC2 console.

Additionally, I've configured the NS DNS server in the website in which I've purchased my domain from.

ns-376.awsdns-47.com
ns-1719.awsdns-22.co.uk
ns-1080.awsdns-07.org
ns-987.awsdns-59.net

I've waited for over 24 hours but I cannot reach the website via the domain name.

What am I doing wrong? I'm super new to AWS and used a few tutorials but can't feature out why it does not work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you might have issues with your DNS at your registrar pointing at the wrong servers.

If I do a WHOIS on your domain, the following is reported:

```
   Name Server: NS-1080.AWSDNS-07.ORG
   Name Server: NS-1719.AWSDNS-22.CO.UK
   Name Server: NS-376.AWSDNS-47.COM
   Name Server: NS-987.AWSDNS-59.NET
```

but according to your NS records from Route 53, you should be using the following:

[image: NS Records]

Comment: I've created a new hosting zone as part of my troubleshooting, I guess I forgot to update them in the domain host.
But the correct one's were updated for weeks but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

The nameservers currently associated with your domain do not match the screenshot. For instance, the aws.net NS record should be `ns-930.awsdns-52.net`, but the one with your registrar is `ns-987.awsdns-59.net`.

Comment: I've created a new hosting zone as part of my troubleshooting, I guess I forgot to update them in the domain host.
But the correct one's were updated for weeks but it did not work.